# JRE and JDK not match

Tags: java

I am getting this error when compiling a project: `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`. I am using JDK 1.6:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)
```

According to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0), the error is due to inconsistency between JRE and JDK. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you very much.

BTW, my platform is OSX 10.8.5.

**Update**

Here is my JAVA_HOME:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6.0`
```

Comment: I'd start with your `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables.

Comment: It seems that you are compiling with JDK 1.6 and some of classes (or libraries) were compiled with JDK 1.7. Try to rebuild the project

Comment: @BalusC: Because my company's codebase is not ready to use JAVA SE 7 yet.

Comment: @BalusC: I was experimenting Java EE 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" because you are trying to run the application in jre 6 which is compiled using jdk 7.

Either compile your application using jdk 6 or upgrade your default jre to 7.

Comment: I realized that one of the dependency of the project was compiled in Java 7. After recompiling that dependency in Java 6, everything works like a charm.

Comment: @LeosLiterak: Yes, you were.